# I need help to implement xml

Tags: android, animation, layout, menu, slider

I found online the working code of a menu slider.
In this code, however, the layout is generated in the code, could someone help me to configure it in a layout file in *. Xml?
Sorry for my bad english.
code:`

```
private boolean Menu_Displayed=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final int width = display.getWidth();

    // menu:
    LinearLayout li_menu = new LinearLayout(this);
    li_menu.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
    li_menu.setOrientation(1);//1 is vertical
    li_menu.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    Button btn1 = new Button(this);
    btn1.setText("button 1");
    btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

    li_menu.addView(btn1);

    //body:
    final HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this){
        @Override
        // do not let hsv consume the click itself. Then the view under the hsv will also consume the click
        //so that the menu will be clicked
        //when menu is not showed up, let hsv be the only view to consume the click.
        //so that the menu will not be clicked
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if(Menu_Displayed){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
    hsv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
    hsv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    hsv.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    hsv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

    final LinearLayout li_body = new LinearLayout(this);
    li_body.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
    li_body.setOrientation(0);//0 is horizantal
    li_body.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    hsv.addView(li_body);

    //body: place holder transparent
    TextView placeholder = new TextView(this);
    placeholder.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    placeholder.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width-100, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
    placeholder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    li_body.addView(placeholder);

    //body: real content
    LinearLayout li_content = new LinearLayout(this);
    li_content.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
    li_content.setOrientation(1);//1 is vertical
    li_content.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);  
    tv1.setText("txt 1");  
    tv1.setTextSize(40);  
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);  

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);  
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
    tv2.setTextSize(50);  
    tv2.setText("txt 2");  
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);  

    //use this button to scroll
    Button btn_showMenu = new Button(this);
    btn_showMenu.setText("Menu");
    btn_showMenu.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn_showMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hsv.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(Menu_Displayed){
                        hsv.smoothScrollTo(width-100, 0);
                    }
                    else{
                        hsv.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                    }
                    Menu_Displayed = !Menu_Displayed;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    li_content.addView(tv1);
    li_content.addView(tv2);
    li_content.addView(btn_showMenu);

    li_body.addView(li_content);

    //add menu and body in to frame
    FrameLayout mainFrame = new FrameLayout(this);  
    mainFrame.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
    mainFrame.addView(li_menu);  
    mainFrame.addView(hsv);  

    //scroll to the body real content to block the menu
    hsv.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            hsv.scrollBy(width-100, 0);             
        }
    });

    setContentView(mainFrame);         
}
```

`

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help, not give you complete working xml files. Which of fucntions do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good implementation of a SlidingMenu, you can try this open sources project:[SideMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) 
To implements the menu swap on you example, is calculating the screen width-100, width cannot be converted to xml, the base view will be like this file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff669900"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fadingEdge="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingRight="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you cannot fully change the JavaCode to an XML View because your view is relaying on the screen mesured with ditected on RunTime.